# How to Add Bootstrap icon in wordpress post

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, wordpress

How to Add Bootstrap icon in wordpress post
i want to know there is any plugin or any custom css edit option available to add bootstrap icon in post.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you mean by "Bootstrap icon" but I'm assuming you mean Glyphicons and those aren't Bootstrap specific.

I'm also assuming you already have Glyphicons loaded through Bootstrap.

If you want to add it in the body of your post, you can either make a shortcode in your theme functions file:

```
   function glyphicon($atts, $content = null) {
          extract(shortcode_atts(
                    array(
             'glyphname' => ''
                    ), $atts)
          );
          return '<i class="glyphicon ' . $glyphname . '"></i>';
    }

add_shortcode('glyphicon', 'glyphicon');
```

Then apply in your post in the class name whatever your glyphicon is that you want, like `[glyphicon class="glyphicon-euro"]` will output `<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-euro"></i>`.

The other option would be to just use HTML (the output above).

Comment: check http://getbootstrap.com/components/ in the given link icons i want to add in my post with bootstrap shortcodes

Comment: Yea, the shortcode will allow you to put any in there as well as inline code.